# How to access git commit message INSIDE sh STEP in a jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh, git-commit, commit-message

I need to access commit message of current fetch from git repository, while completing some `sh` steps of different stages of a pipe in jenkins; but I didn't find any proper solution for it. It would be also nice if I could set the commit message as an environment variable, so that I could access it later on.

Please note that this is not a repetitive question, because none of similar questions on stackoverflow addresses exactly what I need. I need to have commit message in all of `sh` steps of my pipeline.

Comment: Can you provide any code - for example a simplified sh call? What kind of pipeline do you use? Scripted or Declarative?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can get the commit message for the fetched commit ID and set it as an environment variables as follows:

```
stage('get_commit_msg') {
    steps {
        script {
            env.GIT_COMMIT_MSG = sh (script: 'git log -1 --pretty=%B ${GIT_COMMIT}', returnStdout: true).trim()
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use `${GIT_COMMIT_MSG}` in Shell scripts in any downstream stage of your pipeline.